# Defining XML tags/namespaces? Unrecognized warnings

Tags: xml, dtd

I am very new to XML and I don't understand why I'm getting these warnings or what they mean. I'm defining tags to represent a list of games. Here is my dtd file and the warnings the IDE has identified.

[image: my dtd file]

What do these warnings mean and how do I resolve them? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Each error is about an undeclared element. To resolve these specific errors, you would need to declare every element that is referenced in your DTD. (Add `<!ELEMENT` declarations for `name`, `developer`, `engine`, etc.)

Also, you have `name`, `developer`, `engine`, etc. declared as attributes (`<!ATTLIST`).

Instead of just resolving the errors, you should probably decide what you want to be an element and what you want to be an attribute.

Here are some examples. (The DTDs and XML are together to make it easier to test. (The DTD is in an internal subset.) The DTDs can be separated.):

**Using Elements**

```
<!DOCTYPE gamelist [
<!ELEMENT gamelist (game*)>

<!ELEMENT game (data,metadata)>
<!ELEMENT data (name,developer,engine?,releasedate?)>
<!ELEMENT metadata (hoursplayed?,lastplayed?,lastdataupdate)>

<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT developer (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT engine (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT releasedate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT hoursplayed (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastplayed (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastdataupdate (#PCDATA)>

]>
<gamelist>
    <game>
        <data>
            <name></name>
            <developer></developer>
            <engine></engine>
            <releasedate></releasedate>
        </data>
        <metadata>
            <hoursplayed></hoursplayed>
            <lastplayed></lastplayed>
            <lastdataupdate></lastdataupdate>
        </metadata>
    </game>
</gamelist>
```

**Using Attributes**

```
<!DOCTYPE gamelist [
<!ELEMENT gamelist (game*)>

<!ELEMENT game (data,metadata)>

<!ELEMENT data EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST data
          name        CDATA #REQUIRED
          developer   CDATA #REQUIRED
          engine      CDATA #IMPLIED
          releasedate CDATA #IMPLIED    >

<!ELEMENT metadata EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST metadata
          hoursplayed    CDATA #IMPLIED
          lastplayed     CDATA #IMPLIED
          lastdataupdate CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<gamelist>
    <game>
        <data name="" developer="" engine="" releasedate=""/>
        <metadata hoursplayed="" lastplayed="" lastdataupdate=""/>
    </game>
</gamelist>
```

Here are some links that might help:

[XML Essentials](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/core) (Start here first.)

[XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) (Specifically "[Logical Structures](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-logical-struct)".) (Alternatively: [XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/) ("[Logical Structures](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-logical-struct)"))

Comment: Would you mind showing me a short example? Say I wanted to define name as a required string (I'm just finding so many styles online and I can't differentiate between DTD and other uses of XML).